# How to make slightly-modified Android keyboard

Tags: android, android-keypad

I have a sort-of Scrabble-dictionary lookup app in mind (already have Java version working in Windows) in which the user can:

- simply look up a word (e.g., **hacker**)

or

- use wildcards (#, *, ?) to define a pattern for words he might be able to make

E.g.:

- fixed length word: **h???er** (6 letters)
- varying length word: **h*er** (3 to max number of letters)
- fixed length word with no repeated letters: **h###er** (6 letters)
- and unlimited combinations of ? and *: **h?*er** (4 to max number of letters)

I'd hate to have to make my own keypad and worry about positioning the cursor and editing text fields. It would be great if I could remap an existing keypad to look something like this:

[image]

**Is it possible for an Android developer to change the face and action of a key on one of the standard keyboards?** Or is there a **keyboard template** for just such purpose?

***EDIT***

Of course I mean to remap during execution of my app, which, the more I think about it, is probably impossible, except **how does the "enter" key morph into "go" and "next" and stuff like that?**

Likely I'll just have to settle for this setup with a standard qwerty pad and a few buttons, though I'd still have to worry about inserting the 3 wildcards into the text fields:

[image]

Might not be so bad. Agree?

Comment: Yes, googling for "android programming keyboard tutorial" without the quotes should give you what you want.

Comment: @StephanBranczyk!!! THANK YOU!! I hope I don't have to use Eclipse since I never have (first Google hit says to start there), but I'm ON IT!

Comment: The problem is that most tutorials about a specific feature are created at the same time that specific feature was introduced. And since that customizable keyboard feature was introduced a long time ago, almost all the tutorials and sample projects you'll find on that topic will have been created a long time ago using Eclipse (before gradle was even used as the standard build tool for Android projects).

Comment: On that note, may be you should look for a tutorial for creating your own emoji keyboard. That might lead you to something more recent (even that too used Eclipse to build it).

Comment: Thanks, again, @StephanBranczyk. I have installed Eclipse (some time ago) and tried to use it but found it too different from AS, so I gave up. Maybe it's time to revisit it. Having not looked closely yet at the link you provided, I have no idea if I could maybe accomplish it in AS; whatever, I'm going to try soon.

Comment: @StephanBranczyk--You've been so helpful; I've run into errors about `R` and have [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30142931/making-custom-android-keyboard-via-eclipse-tutorial-errors-about-r-references-w) if you'd like to help further:

Comment: @Stephan--I solved the problem by using Android Studio. Took 30 minutes. Refer to [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30143971/creating-custom-android-keyboard-from-well-known-link-compiles-installs-but-n/30144986#30144986). THANK YOU for getting me started.