# Creating custom Android keyboard from well-known link; compiles, installs, but no option for this keyboard shows on device

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I followed the instructions in [this link](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-custom-keyboard-on-android--cms-22615) using Eclipse Luna 2 (4.4.2).

The app compiled, and the apk was installed on my phone, but since it has no activity (which is by design) it can't be run. It's supposed to cause a new keyboard option to appear in the device's `Settings | Language and Input`, but nooooooooooo.

All I did was cut and paste file names and contents, so they're as shown at the link. Here's the project structure, the only item lacking in the link above:

[image]

[image]

Here's console output. All apparently went as it should have:

```
[2015-05-09 14:58:58 - SimpleKeyboard] ------------------------------
[2015-05-09 14:58:58 - SimpleKeyboard] Android Launch!
[2015-05-09 14:58:58 - SimpleKeyboard] adb is running normally.
[2015-05-09 14:58:58 - SimpleKeyboard] No Launcher activity found!
[2015-05-09 14:58:58 - SimpleKeyboard] The launch will only sync the application package on the device!
[2015-05-09 14:58:58 - SimpleKeyboard] Performing sync
[2015-05-09 14:58:58 - SimpleKeyboard] Automatic Target Mode: Unable to detect device compatibility. Please select a target device.
[2015-05-09 14:59:08 - SimpleKeyboard] Uploading SimpleKeyboard.apk onto device 'TA22807EL2'
[2015-05-09 14:59:08 - SimpleKeyboard] Installing SimpleKeyboard.apk...
[2015-05-09 14:59:11 - SimpleKeyboard] Success!
[2015-05-09 14:59:12 - SimpleKeyboard] \SimpleKeyboard\bin\SimpleKeyboard.apk installed on device
[2015-05-09 14:59:12 - SimpleKeyboard] Done!
```

But here's device screen, so it didn't QUITE go as it should have:

[image]

If you can spot an obvious error or omission, PLEASE let me know.

***EDIT #1***

Here's the .java for the project, in case I put something in wrong place, added or omitted an `@Override` etc. No imports were shown on the link:

```
import com.example.simplekeyboard.R;
import android.inputmethodservice.InputMethodService;
import android.inputmethodservice.Keyboard;
import android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView;
import android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView.OnKeyboardActionListener;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputConnection;

public class SimpleIME extends InputMethodService
    implements OnKeyboardActionListener{

    private KeyboardView kv;
    private Keyboard keyboard;
    private boolean caps = false;

    private void playClick(int keyCode){
      AudioManager am = (AudioManager)getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
      switch(keyCode){
      case 32: 
          am.playSoundEffect(AudioManager.FX_KEYPRESS_SPACEBAR);
          break;
      case Keyboard.KEYCODE_DONE:
      case 10: 
          am.playSoundEffect(AudioManager.FX_KEYPRESS_RETURN);
          break;
      case Keyboard.KEYCODE_DELETE:
          am.playSoundEffect(AudioManager.FX_KEYPRESS_DELETE);
          break;              
      default: am.playSoundEffect(AudioManager.FX_KEYPRESS_STANDARD);
      }       
  }

    @Override
    public View onCreateInputView() {
        kv = (KeyboardView)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.keyboard, null);
        keyboard = new Keyboard(this, R.xml.qwerty);
        kv.setKeyboard(keyboard);
        kv.setOnKeyboardActionListener(this);
        return kv;
    }

    @Override
    public void onKey(int primaryCode, int[] keyCodes) {        
        InputConnection ic = getCurrentInputConnection();
        playClick(primaryCode);
        switch(primaryCode){
        case Keyboard.KEYCODE_DELETE :
            ic.deleteSurroundingText(1, 0);
            break;
        case Keyboard.KEYCODE_SHIFT:
            caps = !caps;
            keyboard.setShifted(caps);
            kv.invalidateAllKeys();
            break;
        case Keyboard.KEYCODE_DONE:
            ic.sendKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER));
            break;
        default:
            char code = (char)primaryCode;
            if(Character.isLetter(code) && caps){
                code = Character.toUpperCase(code);
            }
            ic.commitText(String.valueOf(code),1);                  
        }
    } 

    @Override
    public void onPress(int primaryCode) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onRelease(int primaryCode) {            
    }

    @Override
    public void onText(CharSequence text) {     
    }

    @Override
    public void swipeDown() {   
    }

    @Override
    public void swipeLeft() {
    }

    @Override
    public void swipeRight() {
    }

    @Override
    public void swipeUp() {
    }
}
```

***EDIT #2***

I just discovered that `AndroidManifest.xml` in `bin` folder (below) is NOT identical to `AndroidManifest.xml` under app!!:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.simplekeyboard"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <service android:name=".SimpleIME"
            android:label="@string/simple_ime"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_INPUT_METHOD"
            >
            <meta-data android:name="android.view.im" android:resource="@xml/method"/>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.view.InputMethod" />
            </intent-filter>            
        </service>        
    </application>

</manifest>
```

`AndroidManifest.xml` under app:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.simplekeyboard"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    </application>

</manifest>
```

***EDIT #3*** I changed the "short" manifest file to be same as "long" and now I DO GET the `Simple IME` keyboard as an option under `Settings | Language and Input` but the new keyboard (shown below) is NOT shown on device:

[image]

Comment: First, don't put stuff in the Java default package. That probably is not going to work. Beyond that, please post relevant files here, such as your manifest.

Comment: @CommonsWare--I didn't place the code in the default package, the Eclipse wizard did (as far as I know I had no choice), but I'll try to move it. I'll gladly post any code you ask for, but it's all shown in the link, too. I just don't know where to quit including code. It's gonna be long, but here it comes.

Comment: "but it's all shown in the link, too" -- no, it isn't. In particular, any place where the tutorial had you paste stuff into an existing file, notably your manifest, we have no idea what you have.

Comment: @CommonsWare--good point, as I just discovered and posted--there are two `AndroidManifest.xml` files--ONE is as shown at link. I apologize for letting my frustration show.....

Comment: @CommonsWare--mea culpa... DIFFERENT MANIFEST FILES was the problem. New keyboard now DOES SHOW in Settings. (I didn't move source files from default package.)

Comment: But the new keyboard does NOT show when I enter text (e.g., text message, URL in browser...). So NOW what? I'll post more files.

Answer (score 1):

> I just discovered that AndroidManifest.xml in bin folder (below) is NOT identical to AndroidManifest.xml under app!!:

You have two problems here.

First, `bin/` is output. Never modify stuff in `bin/`. So the `<service>` that you put in the manifest needs to go in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file that is in your project root.

Second, assuming that you just move that `<service>` element over to the proper manifest, the Java class needs to be `com.example.simplekeyboard.SimpleIME`. Right now, you have `SimpleIME` in the default package in Java, which is rarely appropriate even in normal Java development, let alone in Android.

So, move the `<service>` element (and any other changes that you made) to the right manifest, and move `SimpleIME` to the right package.

Comment: @Com--OK. I know not to edit whatever, but Eclipse has a different enough structure that I guess I did edit wrong manifest. I just copied what was in the project manifest until back into bin manifest.

Comment: I'm about to address the `service` issue/package issue.;.

Answer (score 0):

The solution: ***Use Android Studio (AS) 1.1.0, NOT ECLIPSE.***

It took 30 minutes to construct the project, correct ZERO errors, and INSTALL ON A DEVICE:

[image]

Seriously, Eclipse is finished for THIS Android Developer. The crud I had to suffer through because of the design and idiotsyncrasies (yes, misspelled) of Eclipse shouldn't have to happen to ANYONE. I chose Eclipse because the link said to do so; I figured, why chance AS?

The procedure described at the link atop this question is GREAT. Just don't develop it in Eclipse.

I'm posting the AS structure just to compare with Eclipse's.

[image]